# Seemingly identical code giving different result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I'm trying to write a matrix (2d list) transpose function for fun, and while working on it I came across this very weird behavior. To me the following functions are pretty much identical (except the other has hard-coded the form of the resulting `new` list).

```
def transpose1(mat):
    new = [[None] * len(mat)] * len(mat[0])

    print("input1:", mat)
    print("new1:", new)

    for j, line in enumerate(mat):
        for i, elem in enumerate(line):
            new[i][j] = mat[j][i]

    return new


def transpose2(mat):
    # only line that differs, but still when
    # printing 'new' they seem identical
    new = [[None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]

    print("input2:", mat)
    print("new2:", new)

    for j, line in enumerate(mat):
        for i, elem in enumerate(line):
            new[i][j] = mat[j][i]

    return new


mat = [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

print("result1:", transpose1(mat))
print()
print("result2:", transpose2(mat))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> input1: [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
> new1: [[None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]
> result1: [[6, 9], [6, 9], [6, 9]]
>
> input2: [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
> new2: [[None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]
> result2: [[4, 7], [5, 8], [6, 9]]
> ```

I just don't understand what difference can the declaration of the `new` lists make to the output. Why does the `transpose1` function give the wrong result, even though the intermediate `new` list looks identical in both cases and the rest of the code is the same?